# Whitney stratification for proper morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $f: X \to \Delta$ be a flat, projective morphism, smooth over the punctured disc $\Delta^*:=\Delta \backslash \{0\}$ and central fiber $f^{-1}(0)$ is a reduced, simple normal crossings divisor. Does there exist a Whitney stratification of $X$ with one strata consisting of $f^{-1}(\Delta^*)$? For example, in the case $X$ is of relative dimension $1$ (i.e., $X$ is a family of curves) and the central fiber is the union of two smooth, irreducible curves $Y_1, Y_2$, is $$\{f^{-1}(\Delta^*)\} \coprod \{(Y_1 \cup Y_2)\backslash (Y_1 \cap Y_2)\} \coprod \{Y_1 \cap Y_2\}$$
a Whitney stratification of $X$? Any idea/reference will be most welcome.

**EDIT**: Assume $X$ is a smooth, complex manifold.